# oracle pl/sql-problem /how I can add some dots after the name to make it reach 10 characters

Tags: oracle, plsql

For Oracle SQL problem how I can add some dots after the  name to make it reach 10 characters such as ( Sara......)
and add dollar simple $ for every 100 in salary, if the salary= 500 so we need to add 5 simple$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `RPAD` function, e.g.

```
SQL> select
  2    rpad(ename, 10, '.') name,
  3    sal,
  4    rpad('$', (sal/100), '$') money
  5  from emp
  6  where deptno = 30;

NAME              SAL MONEY
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
ALLEN.....       1600 $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
WARD......       1250 $$$$$$$$$$$$
MARTIN....       1250 $$$$$$$$$$$$
BLAKE.....       2850 $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
TURNER....       1500 $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
JAMES.....        950 $$$$$$$$$

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```